# Nested Router Outlet With Name Not Working

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I'm struggling with nested router-outlets. My situations looks like this:

I have a `<router-outlet>` in my app.components.html

Then I lazy load my `desktop.module.ts` module via the url: `/d`.

It looks like this:

```
const routes: Routes = [
    { path: 'workout', component: WorkoutComponent, outlet: 'desktop'},
    { path: '', component: DesktopComponent, pathMatch: 'full' }
];


@NgModule({
    imports: [
        CommonModule,
        IonicModule,
        RouterModule.forChild(routes)
    ],
    declarations: [WorkoutComponent, DesktopComponent],
})
export class DesktopModule {}
```

Now inside my `desktop.component.html` I have another outlet like this:

`<router-outlet name="desktop"></router-outlet>`

And also inside the desktop component I want to route to my `WorkoutComponent` using the "desktop" outlet. So with the url: `/d/workout` I display my WorkoutComponent inside the DesktopComponent.

But I can't seem to route to the workout route. I tried this:

`[routerLink]="/d/workout, outlet: { "desktop" }"`

`routerLink="/d/(desktop:workout)"`

But neither are working and I can't find any working answers.

Comment: To display `WorkoutComponent` inside `DesktopComponent` first one should be child of second one. Named router-outlet can't work with siblings. 
So in other words you need to create a parent component with name router-outlet and then use `WorkoutComponent` as a child

Comment: @BotanMan I tried setting the workout route as a child route but I still can't navigate to something like d/workout or d/(desktop:workout). Thanks for the help though!

Comment: @BotanMan never mind I just found a soultion

Answer (score 0):

in desktop.module.ts you need to exports the RouterModule

```
@NgModule({
    imports: [
        CommonModule,
        IonicModule,
        RouterModule.forChild(routes)
    ],
    declarations: [WorkoutComponent, DesktopComponent],
    exports: [RouterModule]
})
```

and you should navigate like this (try ur way, if still not working try this):

```
[routerLink]="['/d/workout']"
routerLink="/d/workout"
```

Comment: It's not working and I also don't understand why it should work if I export my module, I don't need to use my module in another place.

Comment: oh, it's the root app module? ok, my bad. I thought so because of the name of the file

Comment: No worries I just figured out the solution

Comment: I found a great tutorial, I found out I don't need a named outlet, when I set up child routes, it will automatically chose the parents outlet. Here is the tutorial: https://www.tektutorialshub.com/angular-child-routes-nested-routes/