# Use of multiple <router-outlet> under Angular Material (8) is not working

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-routing

Attempting to redefine the problem since I have some more information.

I am working with `Angular Material (8)` - along with the `MDBootstrap` package. 
I have 2 areas. One is an area that deals with logins/authorizations **(AUTH)** and the other is a "dashboard" area (that is to be accessed after login) **(DASHBOARD)**.

[image]

Here is the code that is working with **AUTH** and **MYDASHBOARD** - AUTH is being interpreted by Angular as being the `primary`. I named the second `router-outlet` definition **mydashboard**

**app.component.html**

```
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
<router-outlet name="mydashboard"></router-outlet>
```

**app-routing.module.ts**

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'auth', loadChildren: './kdc/authorization/authorization.module#AuthorizationModule' },
  { path: 'dashboard', loadChildren: './kdc/dashboard/dashboard.module#DashboardModule'  },
  { path: '**' , component: PageNotFoundComponent }

];
```

**authorization-routing.module.ts**

```
export const routesAuth : Routes = [
    { path: 'login' , component: LoginComponent },
    { path: 'register' , component: RegisterComponent },
    { path: 'forgot-pass' , component: ForgotPasswordComponent },
];
```

**NOTE: EVERYTHING FOR (AUTH) IS WORKING - THERE IS NOTHING WRONG WITH THIS PART. THE PROBLEM IS WITH (DASHBOARD)**

[image]

After logging in, the processing goes to the dashboard. I used the code below to send it to the dashboard

**login.component.ts**

```
onLoginSubmit() {
[... snip ...]
        if (this.in_results.count == 0)
          this.errorMsg = 'EMail/Login ID not found';
        else
          // go ahead and navigate to the HOME page
          this.router.navigate(['/dashboard']);  
[... snip ...]
}
```

**dashboard-routing.module.ts**

```
const dashboardroutes: Routes = [
    { path: 'clients', component: ClientsComponent, outlet: 'contentarea'  },
    { path: '', component: HomeComponent, outlet:'mydashboard' },
];
```

**NOTE: EVERYTHING EXECUTES FINE HERE, THE DASHBOARD DOES COME UP AND IT IS STORED IN `<router-outlet name="mydashboard"></router-outlet>` THE PROBLEM COMES WITH USING THE MENU.**

When clicking on the "Clients" area, my expectation is that the "Client Information" will be placed into **`<router-outlet name="contentarea"> </router-outlet>`**  because of how `home.component.html` was defined.

**home.component.html**

```
[... snip ...]
                       <!-- Collapsible link -->
                            <mdb-accordion-item-body>
                                <ul>
                                    <li>  <a [routerLink]="[{ outlets: { primary: 'mydashboard', contentarea : 'clients' }}]" mdbWavesEffect> Press for clients</a></li> 
                                    <li><a href="#" mdbWavesEffect>Link 2</a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </mdb-accordion-item-body>
                        </mdb-accordion-item>

[... snip ...]
<!--Main Layout-->
<main>
    <div class="container-fluid mt-5">
        <router-outlet name="contentarea"> </router-outlet>
    </div>
</main>
<!--/Main layout-->



[... snip ...]
```

**NOTE:**
The processing does not go to: `<router-outlet name="contentarea"> </router-outlet>`

**INSTEAD**

It goes to: `<router-outlet></router-outlet>` located on page: `app.component.html`

**QUESTION: Why does it do this? Am I doing it properly? Is there a better way?**

**I have looked at the following pieces of documentation**

```
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53702674/children-routing-not-working-and-application-redirects-to-the-404-page
https://www.tektutorialshub.com/angular/angular-child-routes-nested-routes/
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52824639/nested-router-outlet-with-name-not-working
https://www.techiediaries.com/angular-router-multiple-outlets/
https://angular.io/guide/router
```

but have not found anything as of yet.

Any information or ideas would be **greatly** appreciated.

TIA

Comment: You have a spelling error inside your routerLink, it should be `dashboard` instead of `dashboaard`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After research (I am new to Angular pretty much), I found that I needed to the following to resolve my problem:

Since I am working with "Lazy Loading", I made sure that the Routes defined in the `xxx-routing.ts` files were properly imported into the `xxx-module.ts` files (I missed this for the Dashboard setup)

I changed the Dashboard setup so that Children were used:

**app-routing.module.ts**

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'auth', loadChildren: './kdc/authorization/authorization.module#AuthorizationModule' },

  { path: 'dashboard', loadChildren: './kdc/dashboard/dashboard.module#DashboardModule'  },
  { path: '**' , component: PageNotFoundComponent }
];
```

**dashboard.routing.module.ts**

```
export const dashboardroutes: Routes = [

    { path: 'landing/:id', component: HomeComponent,
        children: [
            { path: 'clients', component: ClientsComponent, outlet: 'contentarea'  },
        ]},
];
```

I played around with different ways to see if the routers were working. It was during the "playaround time", that I found an answer that worked for me.

```
<!-- WORKS : http://localhost:4200/dashboard/landing/(contentarea:clients) -->

<!-- NOTES: GOES TO BASE HOME PAGE FOR DASHBOARD: http://localhost:4200/dashboard/landing -->

<!-- 404 RESULT: http://localhost:4200/dashboard/landing/landing 
    <li>  <a [routerLink]="['landing',  { outlets: { contentarea : ['clients']}}] " mdbWavesEffect> Press for clients</a></li> -->

<!-- the one below WORKED:  http://localhost:4200/dashboard/landing/(contentarea:clients) -->
        <li>  <a [routerLink]="[{ outlets: { contentarea : ['clients']}}] " mdbWavesEffect> Press for clients</a></li>
```

I got rid of the `<router-outlet name="mydashboard"><router-outlet>` since it did not seem to be needed. I thought that the routers could work in a "sibling" relationship. Have learned that the relationship between different `router-outlet` definitions is more of a "parent-child" relationship.

Answer (score 1):

Did you add `<router-outlet></router-outlet>` in your parent html component?

Comment: Thanks for the response. The "top" component being used (the filename) is: "app.component.html". The instructions being followed are here: https://www.techiediaries.com/angular-router-multiple-outlets/   The "sub-file" being used is "home.component.html"  (it is in the picture above)

Comment: I also found that the relationships need to be parent-child